# Plotting plt various columns with markings

Tags: python, matplotlib

Unsure how to plot the various columns from my data-set. Using df.scatter or plt.plot(kind = 'scatter'...) throws "Line2D object has no property kind error", so I've been using plt.plot(df['colname'], df['colname'], 'o').

Each data point has the following information:

- Date (datetime.date)
- Number of Businesses (integer)
- Big/Small (String of "B" or "S")
- Size (Number of either 1000 or something less than 1000)

I want to create a scatterplot that plots (x = date, y = number of businesses) while marking/coloring each data point by whether its Big/Small and whether it's Size = 1000 or is less than 1000. Not sure how to do this because errors keep being thrown (on my part I need to also weed out the N.A.s)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
fig,ax = plt.subplots()
for k,d in df.groupby('Big/Small'):
    d.plot.scatter(x='date', y='Number of Business',
                   marker='o' if k=='B' else 'x',
                   color=np.where(d['Size']<1000, 'C0','C1'),
                   ax=ax
                  )
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can do this quite easily using the [Seaborn library](https://seaborn.pydata.org/) like this:

```
seaborn.scatterplot('Date', 'NoBus', hue='BigSmall', data=df,
            style=df['Size'].apply(lambda x: '<1000' if x<1000 else '=1000'))
```

Which gives something like this:

[image]